# Convert iterative two sum k to functional

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have this code in Python that finds all pairs of numbers in an array that sum to k:

```
def two_sum_k(array, k):
    seen = set()
    out = set()

    for v in array:
        if k - v in seen:
            out.add((min(v, k-v), max(v, k-v)))
        seen.add(v)
    return out
```

Can anyone help me convert this to Scala (in a functional style)?  Also with linear complexity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the clearest, but folds usually do the trick:

```
def two_sum_k(xs: Seq[Int], k: Int) = {
  xs.foldLeft((Set[Int](),Set[(Int,Int)]())){ case ((seen,out),v) =>
    (seen+v, if (seen contains k-v) out+((v min k-v, v max k-v)) else out)
  }._2
}
```

Comment: Looks a bit complicated, but was the fastest in a short test with 10000 Elements, about 10% not suitable for building a sum. Faster than mine.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a classic case of when a *for-comprehension* can provide additional clarity

```
scala> def algo(xs: IndexedSeq[Int], target: Int) =
   | for {
   |   i <- 0 until xs.length
   |   j <- (i + 1) until xs.length if xs(i) + xs(j) == target
   | }
   | yield xs(i) -> xs(j)
algo: (xs: IndexedSeq[Int], target: Int)scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)]
```

Using it:

```
scala> algo(1 to 20, 15)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)] = Vector((1,14), (2,13), (3,12), (4,11), (5,10), (6,9), (7,8))
```

I think it also doesn't suffer from the problems that your algorithm has

Comment: This have a worse big-oh than the python solution, assuming a HashSet.

Comment: Yes - I'm sure there are more efficient solutions

Comment: what do you think of my solution?

Answer (score 3):

You could just filter for (k-x <= x) by only using those x as first element, which aren't bigger than k/2:

```
def two_sum_k (xs: List[Int], k: Int): List [(Int, Int)] =
  xs.filter (x => (x <= k/2)).
    filter (x => (xs contains k-x) && (xs.indexOf (x) != xs.lastIndexOf (x))).
      map (x => (x, k-x)).distinct
```

My first filter on line 3 was just `filter (x => xs contains k-x).`, which failed as found in the comment by Someone Else. Now it's more complicated and doesn't find (4, 4).

```
scala> li
res6: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5)

scala> two_sum_k (li, 8) 
res7: List[(Int, Int)] = List((3,5))
```

Comment: This is incomplete.  Given xs = (2,3,5,6) and k = 4 it returns (2,2), which it should not.

Comment: You're right. I made an improvement, tested it, tested the code of others. What do you expect for `f((2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5), 8)` to be returned? 4 times (3, 5)? I guess you don't. What does the python code do? Since there are sets, I guess every combination only once. Mh. A final `distinct` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
def twoSumK(xs: List[Int], k: Int): List[(Int, Int)] = {
  val tuples = xs.iterator map { x => (x, k-x) }
  val potentialValues = tuples map { case (a, b) => (a min b) -> (a max b) }
  val values = potentialValues filter { xs contains _._2 }
  values.toSet.toList
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, a direct translation would be this:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

def twoSumK[T : Numeric](array: Array[T], k: T) = {
  val num = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
  import num._

  val seen = mutable.HashSet[T]()
  val out: mutable.Set[(T, T)]  = mutable.HashSet[(T, T)]()

  for (v <- array) {
    if (seen contains k - v) out += min(v, k - v) -> max(v, k - v)
    seen += v
  }

  out
}
```

One clever way of doing it would be this:

```
def twoSumK[T : Numeric](array: Array[T], k: T) = {
  val num = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
  import num._

  // One can write all the rest as a one-liner
  val s1 = array.toSet
  val s2 = s1 map (k -)
  val s3 = s1 intersect s2

  s3 map (v => min(v, k - v) -> max(v, k - v))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
def two_sum_k(xs: List[Int], k: Int): List[(Int, Int)] ={
      xs.map(a=>xs.map(b=>(b,a+b)).filter(_._2 == k).map(b=>(b._1,a))).flatten.collect{case (a,b)=>if(a>b){(b,a)}else{(a,b)}}.distinct
}
```

Comment: This fails the basic requisite: all numbers in the answer must be contained in `xs`.